# CorePlot. Сложение двух (и более) линий

Tags: objective-c, swift

Уже неделю бьюсь на проблемой с CorePlot. У меня есть записи в CoreData, которые содержат массив точек (время и значение). У каждой записи ровно 100 этих точек.

Проблема в том, что мне надо нарисовать одну линию на графике по следующему принципу (грубый пример):

1) У нас есть 2 записи у одной точки идут с 10.00 до 12.00 и значение у каждой равно 2 (на самом деле график рисуется по формулам). И есть вторая запись в которой записи идут с 11.00 до 13.00 и значение у них равно 3

2)Мне надо нарисовать только одну линию, которая будет с 10.00 до 11.00 иметь значение 2, с 11.00 до 12.00 иметь значение 5 (сумму двух пересекающихся по времени линий) и с 12.00 до 13.00 равно иметь значение 3

Проблема в том, что графики строятся из 100 точек и время у какой-нибудь точки из первой линии и точки из второй может отличаться за минуту, то есть я не могу просто сравнить их и если одинаковые - увеличить значение у одной, а вторую удалить (как минимум потому что я не знаю эту самую разницу).

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким и сможет помочь или натолкнуть на нужную мысль, потому что у меня уже опускаются руки

Comment: не очень понятно объяснили почему нельзя просто сложить. как насчет сделать новый массив и результат сложения положить в него?

Comment: Потому что эти линии строятся из 100 точек (и у каждой своё значение и своё время), то есть у нас может быть точка 10.21 у одной линии и 10.25 у другой. Они как бы очень рядом, но всё равно значение времени у них разное, то есть как определить, что они подходят для складывания?

Comment: округлить до секунд?